# Get name of abstract type

Tags: scala, traits, type-systems

I'm trying to create a trait that would provide the name of the abstract type that is added in the sub-class:

```
trait T {
  type T
  def myClassOf[T:ClassTag] = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass
  def getType = {
    myClassOf[T].getSimpleName
  }
}

class TT extends T {
  type T = String
}
```

However, this fails to compile:

```
Error:(7, 15) not enough arguments for method myClassOf: (implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T.this.T])Class[_].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
    myClassOf[T].getSimpleName
             ^
```

But it works fine if I move the `getType` method to the sub-class. Can someone explain why and whether there is a way to do this call from the sub-class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the point where you call `myClassOf[T]` `T` is still abstract, so the compiler can not generate a `ClassTag` for it. You can fix it by delaying the generation of the `ClassTag[T]` until `T` is known.

```
trait Trait {
  type T
  def myClassOf[A:ClassTag] = implicitly[ClassTag[A]].runtimeClass
  def getType(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) = {
    myClassOf[T].getSimpleName
  }
}

class Sub extends Trait {
  type T = String
}
```

If adding an implicit parameter is impossible for some reason I think the best way is probably requiring some method `getClassT` to be implemented in subclasses. Since its return type is `Class[T]` it's difficult to provide a wrong implementation in a subclass.

```
trait Trait {
  type T
  def getType = {
    getClassT.getSimpleName
  }
  def getClassT: Class[T]
}

class Sub extends Trait {
  type T = String
  def getClassT = classOf[T]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: Is there any way that I can call the method `getType` from within the same trait? I'd like to use it in a method where the signature is fixed, so that it'd need to pass the implicit parameters

Comment: I don't immediately see a way.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the above answers, while good are now obsolete as of scala 2.10.
the preferred method now is to use TypeTag or ClassTag.

As described in the [docs (see below)](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) you can now use them in implicit param lists or context bounds to do this kind of thing:-

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def paramInfo[T: TypeTag](x: T): Unit = {
  val targs = typeOf[T] match { case TypeRef(_, _, args) => args }
  println(s"type of $x has type arguments $targs")
}

scala> paramInfo(42)
type of 42 has type arguments List()

scala> paramInfo(List(1, 2))
type of List(1, 2) has type arguments List(Int)
```

see [scala docs on Typetags](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html)

see [api docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20160915014553/http://www.scala-lang.org:80/api/2.11.7/scala-reflect/#scala.reflect.api.TypeTags)